# Unable to run Angular4 application

Tags: angular, lambda, npm

I have set up a Sinopia server in which I have published my private modules, I am importing these modules in a common UI framework and trying to run it.

Following is my app.module.ts code where I am importing the modules

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRouting } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FlashAppModule } from '@netapp/flash-advisor-ui';
import { UIComponentModule } from '../ui/ui.component.module'
import { PerformanceAppModule } from '@netapp/performance-dashboard';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FlashAppModule,
        PerformanceAppModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRouting,
        UIComponentModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when I am starting the application `npm start` I get the following error. 
I have not written a single line of code using lambda func. I have just imported these modules that's it.

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the
>   function o
>       r lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 194:50 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol NgModule in C:/sinopia/tes
>       t/gtest/node_modules/@netapp/flash-advisor-ui/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol FlashAppModule in C:/sinopia/test/gt
>       est/node_modules/@netapp/flash-advisor-ui/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol FlashAppModule in
>   C:/sinopia/test/gtest/node_modules/@n
>       etapp/flash-advisor-ui/src/app/app.module.ts
>           at positionalError (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23957:35)
>           at simplifyInContext (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23800:27)
>           at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23814:13)
>           at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23263:41)
>           at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:126:31)
>           at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:101:26)
>           at C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:117:27
>           at Array.reduce (native)
>           at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:116:10)
>           at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:52:22)
>           at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:79:3
>       9)
>           at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
>           at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\sinopia\test\gtest\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>       webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: looks like you have function call somewhere in your code like function(){}.... post your code, otherwise we won't be able to help!

Comment: It's really hard to answer a question with no source code, and just a link to an image of the error message. In order to get high quality answers, you really need to ask highly detailed questions - what are you doing, what problem are you experiencing, what have you tried. Look at other posted questions to get a sense of the level of detail you should be including in order to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

From the error I can see that you're using AOT. Yes, AOT doesn't support arrow functions as it said in the error text. And yes, please post error text right in the question body.
P.S. Nothing new I can say - please check again that your code valid for AOT compilation.